# How do i find the largest indexer in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a program which needs to enter values in an array in a loop. I need a way to find the largest index:

```
string[] stuff = { "Headphones", "Pen", "stapler" };
string[] alreadysaid = { "Headphones" };

foreach (string stuffs in stuff)
{
    if (alreadysaid.Contains(stuffs))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("already said");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stuffs);
        // add said element to alreadysaid
    }
}
```

Comment: `myArray.Length - 1`?

Comment: What is a `largest indexer`? Please **[edit]** the question and explain, hopefully give examples of expected output as well. Also note that in C# you can't make arrays grow, you might better use a `List<string>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `HashSet<string>` instead of `string[]` for `alreadysaid`; now all you have to do is to `Add` the `stuffs`:

```
HashSet<string> alreadysaid = new HashSet<string>() { "Headphones" };

foreach (string stuffs in stuff) 
{
    if (alreadysaid.Add(stuffs)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stuffs);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("already said");
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to get `alreadysaid` as an `string[]` you can use *Linq*:

```
string[] arraySaid = alreadysaid.ToArray();
```

Comment: Does Add method return bool?
`public void Add(T item)`

Comment: @Stanislav Molchanovsky: Yes, `Add(T item)` returns `bool` in case of `HashSet<T>`

Comment: Note that a set is unordered, so `alreadysaid.ToArray()` does not necessarily return the items in the order they were added.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the wrong implementation.
By the way it seems that this is not a very good name for the method, `TryAdd` name would be more suitable.

Comment: @StanislavMolchanovsky - well, the "adding" always "works" (there is no "try"), the return value just indicates, if the value to add was already contained in the set (`false`) or not (`true`). -- i.e. if it is a "new" value or not.

Comment: @Corak However, `ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd` returns false if the key already exists for example

Answer (score 0):

Use `LINQ` to do that

```
int maxIndex = stuff.ToList().IndexOf(stuff.Max());
```

Comment: This could fail when the last Item is duplicated in the array. For example ,  { "Headphones", "stapler" ,"Pen", "stapler" };